# Create view using Join statement

Tags: sql-server, left-join

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[view_item_ledger_entry](item_no, item_description, location, quantity)
AS
    SELECT 
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_] AS item_no,
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item].[Description] AS item_description,
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS location,
        SUM([ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry].Quantity) AS quantity
    FROM    
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item] ON [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]=[ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item].[No_]
    WHERE    
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_] LIKE '5%'
    GROUP BY 
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_],
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
```

My question is: the above SQL creates a view, but I get lots of errors:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 20
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item
>   Ledger Entry.Item No_" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 20
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item.No_" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 21
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item Ledger
>   Entry.Item No_" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 22
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry.Item No_" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 23
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry.Location Code" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 14
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry.Item No_" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 15
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item.Description" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 16
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry.Location Code" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure view_item_ledger_entry, Line 17
>   The multi-part identifier "ABGSRV11\ABIG.ASKUPROD.dbo.ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry.Quantity" could not be bound.

Comment: Have you heard of using aliases?  It looks like a database or table name is wrong somewhere.  Check your schema.

Comment: i can not use aliases because i'm trying to create the view from an ERP data base which the table name and everything is already set by the implmenter by making the server linked server in my local data base, so i used the fully qualified name of the tables

Comment: for example this query works fine, the error comes when i add the left outer join

Comment: CREATE VIEW [dbo].[view_item_ledger_entry](item_no,item_description,location,quantity)
AS 
    SELECT  [Item No_],'',[Location Code],sum(Quantity) as quantity 

    FROM     [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.[dbo].[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry]
 WHERE quantity <> 0 AND [Item No_] LIKE '5%'
 GROUP BY [Item No_],[Location Code]


GO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the

> Multipart Identifier Could not be bound

exception when the specified column is not available in your table. So make sure that the columns listed in your `Select` statements exist in your tables and also you have specified the correct table name.

Also, I suggest using alias names for joins so that it will make the coding easier and your code will look more comfortable for someone else who might be debugging it later.

Your above code can be re-written like below (still make sure the column names):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[view_item_ledger_entry]
(
    item_no,
    item_description,
    location,
    quantity
)
AS
    SELECT 
        ENT.[Item No_] AS item_no,
        ITM.[Description] AS item_description,
        ENT.[Location Code] AS location,
        SUM(ENT.Quantity) AS quantity
    FROM 
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item Ledger Entry] ENT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        [ABGSRV11\ABIG].ASKUPROD.dbo.[ASKU PLC$Item] ITM ON ENT.[Item No_]= ITM.[No_]
    WHERE 
        ENT.[Item No_] LIKE '5%'
    GROUP BY 
        ENT.[Item No_],
        ITM.[Description],
        ENT.[Location Code]
```